# How to draw with few colors

Tags: objective-c, colors, charts, draw, drawrect

He i'm working on simple pie chart, and i've got problem when i'm drawing it.
I want to change color of every piece of pie chart, but when method drawRect: is called my pie chart is in signle color. How make it correctly?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [values count]; i++) {
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.2*i, 0.2*i, 0.2*i, 1);

    [bezierPath moveToPoint:chartCenter];

    startAngle = endAngle;

    endAngle = startAngle + [self degreesToRadians:[values[i] floatValue]*step];
    NSLog(@"%.2f, %.2f", startAngle, endAngle);

    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:chartCenter radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:1];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:chartCenter];

    [bezierPath fill];
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any change in colour? i.e. different shades of grey?

Comment: i want to change start gray color to ligther gray by incement `i` when i set the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my code is working correctly. I've got some errors in drawing method and i create circles not arcs. sorry for this.

The problem was in this method:

-(float)degreesToRadians:(float)degrees{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}

I use `M_1_PI` instead of `M_PI` and my arcs were circles.

Answer (score 1):

Im am not 100% sure, but I think you have to use `-[UIColor setFill]` to set the fill color for a bezier path, e.g.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2*i alpha:1.0];
[UIColor setFill];
```

You should probably also start a new bezier path for each chart segment.